# Can a dependent select be made only using data from the same table?

Tags: html, oracle, jsp

i have a oracle database with a table that it have these camps:

```
CREATE TABLE "OCEXPNP"."OCEX_UEA" 
(   "ID_UEA" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "N_DEP" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "N_PROV" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "N_DIST" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE )
```

Well i'm trying to make my second select show a specific data that depending on the first select. First, I completed fill a "select department" but when I compare this first selection in the query of my "select province" doesn't show me data of province on the page.

This is my jsp:

```
<div class="input-field col s4">                                    
<select name="department">
<option value="">Select department</option>                                             
<% 
    ConectaDB con=new ConectaDB();
    try{
        con.conectar();
        String sql="select unique(n_dep) from OCEX_UEA order by n_dep asc";
        con.st=con.conexion.createStatement(); 
        con.rt=con.st.executeQuery(sql);
        while (con.rt.next()){
         out.println("<option value=con.rt.getString(n_dep)>"+con.rt.getString("n_dep")+"</option>");
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
          out.print(e.toString()); 
        }
%>                                                      
</select>
<label for="department"><Strong>Select Department:</Strong></label>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s4">                                    
<select name="province">
<option value="">Select Province</option>                                               
<%      
    try{
        con.conectar();
        String sql="select unique(n_prov) from ocex_uea where n_dep = "+con.rt.getString(n_dep)+"order by n_prov asc;";
        con.st=con.conexion.createStatement(); 
        con.rt=con.st.executeQuery(sql);
        while (con.rt.next()){
         out.println("<option value=con.rt.getString(n_prov)>"+con.rt.getString("n_prov")+"</option>");
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
          out.print(e.toString()); 
        }
%>                                                      
</select>
<label for="province"><Strong>Select Province:</Strong></label>
</div>
```

I'm learning about JSP and i'll hope you help me.

Comment: what happens when enclosed `n_dep` in quotes as `con.rt.getString("n_dep")` for the `Select Province` part ..?

Comment: I should capture the data that selects the first select to be able to pass that data in the select but it does not show anything, I believe that there in all that part is my error

Answer (score 0):

You should give alias to the column you select

```
select unique(n_dep) n_dep from OCEX_UEA order by n_dep asc
```

And the same for the second query.